# Error linking with LLVM/Clang on MSVS 2022

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, clang, vcpkg

I am having trouble compiling a project with LLVM/clang toolchain in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, despite having installed the vcpkg LLVM/clang addons for MSVS.

It is a C++ project that compiles/runs fine with MSVS default compiler (v143).

However, switching to LLVM clang-cl (via Configuration Properties) results in:

`could not open 'C:\Users\sam\Documents\sam\code\packages\msvs\vcpkg-2021.11.26\vcpkg\installed\\x86-windows\debug\lib\*.lib': invalid argument`

`C:\Users\sam\Documents\sam\code\projects\frameworks\test\projectname\lld-link`

I have found this unresolved bug on the [vcpkg github](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/4359), for which there was apparently a workaround that no longer works.

I have tried reinstalling clang in vcpkg, and tried changing numerous library-related fields that might have a wildcard *.lib.  No luck.  I am not sure if this is a linker problem, an LLVM problem, or (given the dearth of people experiencing the same problem) a problem unique to me.

I am really excited to use LLVM, so any help getting me on my way would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right click and open the project properties you should have a property called vcpkg. You can deactivate the auto link feature of vcpkg there. Another solution would be to remove the vcpkg msbuild integration completely and use a sane buildsystem like cmake.

Comment: You may find this amusing: your solution did not work the first time around 2 years ago.  But I got the same error again 2 minutes ago, Googled the error, and this was the first result...and THIS time it did solve the problem.  What a time to be alive.  Cheers m8